# How to code a Delaunay Triangle pattern using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

The site http://www.lahautesociete.com/ exhibits the use of a geometric background design whose vertices move in random directions.

I've inspected the DOM and they're making use of canvas to produce the pattern. I'd like to replicate this pattern, but the thing is, even though I have some decent canvas experience, I have no idea where to start on this one.

Is there some sort of mathematical formula that produces the triangular pattern? How would I select the individual vertices? If you can guide me in the right direction, please let me know, thanks!

This is pretty much the only code I could grab pertaining to the canvas design (unhelpful, I know):

```
<canvas width="1280" height="353" style="width: 1280px;height: 353px;"></canvas>
```

There's a minified JavaScript file that I unminified, but I've been unable to identify anything relating to canvas within it.

**Update:** Looks like the deminifier I used couldn't handle the gigantic JS file the site uses. On exploration, I discovered that the site makes use of Three.js

**Update (Jan 21, 2016):** After a lot of research, I've discovered that the name of the pattern I'm looking to code is called a Delhaunay Triangle. I've come across a few external resources that I look to examine and analyze:

- http://christophermanning.org/projects/voronoi-diagram-with-force-directed-nodes-and-delaunay-links
- http://codepen.io/blascone/pen/AoFCx
- http://codepen.io/kenjiSpecial/pen/BGhrm

Comment: Please grab any relevant code from the link you have referenced and paste it as part of your answer. That way if/when the link goes dead, there is something in your question that users can go by. Please read: **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** for reference

Comment: This looks like a physics simulation, with each vertex repelling the others. You might look at D3's force-directed graphs as one example of implementing this in JS: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout

Comment: It is done via WebGL but it is not that difficult a algorithm and can be done in canvas using 2D but would require a reasonable machine or a lower resolution to run at 60FPS

Comment: Your question is too broad to be a good question on Stackoverflow so you might consider deleting your question. Here's a starting point for you: https://codepen.io/dissimulate/pen/KrAwx